# program to write initials of string

Tags: c, string

I Am trying to make a program to make the user to enter his first name then middle then last name each followed by space like this example:

sample input: *mark brown ashraf*

sample output: *m b a*

and when i debug i got "access violation error"

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char name[100];
    int i=0;
    printf("Enter the name :");
    gets(name);
    while (name[i]!='\0')
    {
        if (name[i]==' ')
        {
            i++;
            printf("%c",name[i+1]);
        }
        i++;
    }
    getch();
}
```

"now it dont give me the first initial but printed the rest of initials "

Comment: In the innermost `if`, Pick one: 'i + 1' or 'i++'. (You want `i + 1` here and you'll also want to check that the next letter isn't also a space.)

Comment: `name[i + 1]` is a `char`, but you print it as a string with `%s`. Use the `char` format specifier `%c` or use the `putchar()` function.

Comment: `space` terminated is not equal to null-terminated.

Comment: Make a function that reads to a space or the end of the string.

Comment: @MOehm i have made it '%c' but still not giving me the right initials

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The access violation happens, because you use the wrong format specifier in your `printf` call.

```
printf("%s", name[i+1]);
```

should be

```
printf("%c", name[i+1]);
```

or maybe even more directly:

```
putchar(name[i+1]);
```

The violation occurs, because `%s` expects a pointer, which the printing function then dereferences. The `char` value you pass isn't a valid memory address.

Please switch on compiler warnings. They can usually tell you that your format string doesn't match the arguments.

**Edit** Besides the access violation, there are more problems in your program:

- You increment `i` twice after a space, so that you actually print the second letter of each word. (Or even a space if your input is "Taylor C Huckleberry").
- You don't catch the first word, unless your input begins with a space character.
- You could end up printing the `'\0'` character when your input has trailing spaces.
- You could print additional spaces if your input has subsequent spaces.

There are also some formal programming errors:

- `main` is supposed to return an `int`, but your code never does.
- You use the obsolete `gets`, which has been superseded with the more secure `fgets`. (Unformtunately, `fgets`keeps a trailing newline, but it shouldn't matter for your code.)

In my opinion, a better approach is to keep track of the previously read character and to print the initial only if the previous char was a space and the current one is a letter. The header `<ctype.h>` provides the handy functions `isspace` and `isalpha` to check this. The previously read character starts off as a space character, so that you catch the first word:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    char name[100];
    char prev = ' ';        /* pretend there's a space before the string */
    int n = 0;              /* number of initials printed */
    int i = 0;

    printf("Enter the name: ");
    fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin);

    while (name[i]!='\0') {
        if (isalpha(name[i]) && isspace(prev)) {
            if (n++) putchar(' ');
            putchar(name[i]);
        }
        prev = name[i];
        i++;
    }
    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sir isn't there a potential prob of array out of bound access?

Comment: @Gopi: Yes, the program has many more issues. I have addressed only the segmentation violation.

Comment: @MOehm now it works but not giving me the first initial

Comment: @TadrosEbrahim: I've added more information about the logical error in your program, which misses the first word.

Comment: I think as there is a need to display a space between the initials.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: Okay, I've extended the code so that it prints a space before each initial, but not before the first. (I hope no-one will complain that the code doesn't uppercase the initials and that it doesn't treat non-Latin characters properly, because it doesn't.)

Answer (score 1):

```
while (name[i]!='\0')
{
    if (name[i]==' ')
    {
        i++;
        printf("%s",name[i+1]);
    }
    i++;
}
```

SInce you are incrementing `i` twice inside the loop there is a possibility that you might have access array out of bound. This is a potential error.

`gets()` is no more a standard and you should use `fgets()` instead which will handle buffer overflow.